# Sum of correlated normal random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, correlation

Suppose I have two correlated random variables, that were generated in the following way:
\begin{align*}
X_1 &\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\\
X_1' &\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\\
X_2 &= \rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\cdot X_1'\\
Y_1 &= \mu_1+\sigma_1 X_1\\
Y_2 &= \mu_2+\sigma_2 X_2.
\end{align*}

Now, is it true that $Y_1+Y_2$ (or, more generally $\alpha_1 Y_1+\alpha_2Y_2$) normally distributed? (I can easily calculate the mean and the variance of
$\alpha_1 Y_1+\alpha_2Y_2$, but I am not sure about the distribution...)

**EDIT:** just to clarify, $X_1$ and $X_1'$ are independent.

Comment: You mean $X_2 \sim \rho X_1 +\sqrt{1-\rho^2} X_1'$?

Comment: Sure, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that $X_2 \mathbf{\,=\,} \rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\cdot X_1'$?

Comment: Sure, fixed as well, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha_1 Y_1 + \alpha_2 Y_2$ is a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_1^\prime$ - that is $\alpha_1 Y_1 + \alpha_2 Y_2 = \beta X_1 + \beta^\prime X_1^\prime$ for some $\beta, \beta^\prime$ that are a bit of a pain to calculate.  Linear combinations of independent normal random variables are normal; there are [several proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Proof_using_characteristic_functions) of this (nontrivial, but well-known) fact.   So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Right, I should have seen this. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael Lugo Here $X_1$ and $X_1'$ are correlated, how can you deduce $\alpha_1 Y_1 + \alpha_2 Y_2$ is normal?

Comment: Bach: as @ntt has pointed out, this only holds if $X_1$ and $X_1^\prime$ are independent.  I'd assumed from your notation that you intended independence there, but if that's not the case then my answer is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I meant that they are independent. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: @Bach They should be uncorrelated. Because this assumption is enough to get the independence.

Comment: @ntt Uncorreletedness of two r.v. with given normal marginals does not imply independence. .

Comment: @NCh You are right. I'm sorry Bach, NCh. It is only true for Gaussian vector. I'm so shortsighted :(

Answer (score 3):

Take $X_1 \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and let $Z$ be a r.v. with $P(Z =-1)=P(Z=1)=1/2$ and $X_1, Z$ are independent. Denote $X_1'=Z\cdot X_1$, then $X_1' \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. However $(X_1, X_1')$ is not Gaussian as $X_1+X_1'$ is not normal. Then $X_2$ should not Gaussian, perhaps $X_2$ will be Gaussian with some specific values of $\rho$. We have $Y_1$ is Gaussian, $Y_2$ is not Gaussian then $Y_1+Y_2$ is probably not Gaussian in general.